# Prove that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is not cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Prove that  $\mathbb{Q}  \times \mathbb{Q}$  is not cyclic.

My  attempt:Suppose  $\mathbb{Q}  \times \mathbb{Q}$  is cyclic.Then there exist  a  generator  $(x,y)$  where  $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$

we know that  every element of the group $\mathbb{Q}  \times \mathbb{Q}$   has the form  $(nx, ny )$  where $n \in \mathbb{Z} $.

Let  $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$, then we have $(px,py) =(1,0) $  and  $(qx,qy)=(0,1) $.

This  implies  $px=1$ and  $qy=1$.

So, $p= q \neq 0$.

Again  we  have $py=0$  and $qx=0$.

This implies $x= y = 0$.

This shows that $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} =(nx, ny )=(n\cdot 0,n\cdot 0)=\langle(0,0)\rangle$

This is a  contradiction, so $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is not cyclic.

Is it true?

Comment: Can anybody make any sense of this at all?

Comment: @TonyK you means  my   attempt isn't good enough

Comment: You introduce, but never define, $x$ and $y$. Given that you never let anyone know who $x$ and $y$ are, the rest is incomprehensible absent guesses, and a proof is not supposed to force the reader to make guesses.

Comment: jasmine, it makes no sense. I don't understand any of it.

Comment: What are $x,y$? You claim "we have $(px, py)=(1, 0)$. How do you know that? Where did that equation come from?

Comment: @5xum  That my assumption because  $(1,0)$  doesn't  generate  $(0,1)$.

Comment: @jasmine What is your assumption? Which statement, precisely, is your assumption? Also, you didn't answer my first question. What are $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @5xum i edited.

Comment: @jasmine Ahh, now it's much clearer. What is still a little confusing is the following: You say "let $p,q\in\mathbb Z$, then we have $(px, py)=(1,0)$". Are you saying that the equation $(px, py)=(1,0)$ is true **for all** values of $p$, or that there exists **some** value $p$ for which the equation holds? Because saying "let $a\in A$" is used to denote that whatever we will say about $a$ is true for **all** values in $A$. But what you wrote is not true for **all** values of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @jasmine And another thing, you say that because from the assumption that the group is cyclic, there exists a generator $(x,y)$ such that $x,y\in\mathbb Z$. This is not necessarily the case. If a group $G$ is cyclic, there exists some $g\in G$ such that $g$ is the generator of $G$. So, you should write $x,y\in\mathbb Q$ instead of $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ supposed to denote the additive group (where the group operation is coordinate-wise addition)?

If you want to prove it is not a cyclic group, then assume that it *was* a cyclic group. Then there would be one fixed group element, say $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ which was the *generator* for the group. This means that every member of $\mathbb{Q}  \times \mathbb{Q}$ could be written on the form:
$$
(x,y)+(x,y)+\dots+(x,y)=(nx,ny)
$$
or:
$$
(-x,-y)+(-x,-y)+\dots+(-x,-y)=(nx,ny)
$$
for some integer $n$. ($n=0$, the empty sum, is allowed.) But this cannot be true. It is clear that the generator $(x,y)$ cannot be the neutral element $(0,0)$ (it generates only the trivial subgroup). Then consider the element $(\frac{x}{2},\frac{y}{2})$, clearly a member of $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$. It is clear that $(\frac{x}{2},\frac{y}{2})$ cannot be written as $(nx,ny)$ for *integer* $n$.